# Tryed to install mb-lab- master to blender user preference error message invalid syntax

Tags: python

tried to install MB-Lab-master from github and receive this message from the user preference menu on Blender 2.79b 
see: https://github.com/animate1978/MB-Lab/wiki/Installation
second question is , If I can get it to load , does it add a tab
in the user menu the same way the makehuman add-on did ?
and the entire error message reads :

Traceback(most recent call last):
File"C:\Program files|Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py.line 331 in enable mod=*import*(module_name)

File "C:\users\thund\App Data\Roaming\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\MB-Lab-master_init_.py, line 1241 filter_glob: bpy.props.StringProperty(
                      ^
SyntaxError : Invalid Syntax

so can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

That version has been coded for Blender 2.80 Beta.

You want this version for Blender 2.79 - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Wxly5xEYQwPvCvo1Gn95r7iPk02PTWD-